# ¿Cómo realizar varias consultas SQL a la vez en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, android

Tengo que ejecutar un archivo PHP desde una app android pasándole 2 parámetros para que el PHP elimine los registros que coincidan con esos parámetros en varias tablas distintas de una base de datos mysql. Los párametros siempre serían los mismos pero los nombres de las columnas son diferentes en cada tabla.

He conseguido que el PHP reciba los parámetros correctamente desde la app y elimine los registros correspondientes en una tabla, pero como he comentado antes necesito que haga lo mismo en otras tablas distintas utilizando los mismos parámetros recibidos.

He probado utilizando el comando `mysqli_multi_query` pero al ejecutar el php en el navegador me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM table_packs WHERE USER_PACK = '' AND PASSWORD_PACK = ''DELETE FRO...' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\studyBonusGame\DeleteBackupOnline.php:33 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\studyBonusGame\DeleteBackupOnline.php(33): mysqli_multi_query(Object(mysqli), 'DELETE FROM tab...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\studyBonusGame\DeleteBackupOnline.php on line 33
```

El código PHP que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$database = "database";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$content = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);


$USER = $content['USER'];
$PASSWORD = $content['PASSWORD'];


$sql = "DELETE FROM table_players WHERE userPlayer = '$USER' AND passwordPlayer = '$PASSWORD'";

$sql .= "DELETE FROM table_packs WHERE USER_PACK = '$USER' AND PASSWORD_PACK = '$PASSWORD'";

$sql .= "DELETE FROM table_questions WHERE USER_QUE = '$USER' AND PASSWORD_QUE = '$PASSWORD'";


if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Deleted correctly";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: ¿Y que te impide ejecutar varias veces un mysqli_query con distintas variables $sqlX en lugar de intentar agregarlas todas en una?   Asi podrás depurar mejor las consultas, si alguna falla.

Comment: @masterguru Tienes razón. Voy a intentar crear el código con consultas independientes. Muchas gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes terminar las sentencias SQL con su respectivo punto y coma (;) :

```
<?php
$sql = "DELETE FROM table_players WHERE userPlayer = '$USER' AND passwordPlayer = '$PASSWORD';";

$sql .= "DELETE FROM table_packs WHERE USER_PACK = '$USER' AND PASSWORD_PACK = '$PASSWORD';";

$sql .= "DELETE FROM table_questions WHERE USER_QUE = '$USER' AND PASSWORD_QUE = '$PASSWORD'";
?>
```

Recomendación: No concatenar parámetros, puedes quedar vulnerable a Inyecciones SQL, preferiblemente usar prepared statements.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, justo ese era el problema. Y gracias por el consejo sobre Inyecciones SQL, se me había pasado por alto

Answer (score 0):

La cuestión es que al concatenar las instrucciones con el `.=` no estas poniendo el **punto coma que pide SQL al final de cada instruccion**. Tu resultado sería:

```
DELETE FROM table_players WHERE userPlayer = 'X' AND passwordPlayer = 'X'
DELETE FROM table_packs WHERE USER_PACK = 'X' AND PASSWORD_PACK = 'X'
DELETE FROM table_questions WHERE USER_QUE = 'X' AND PASSWORD_QUE = 'X'
```

Entonces ahí el SQL se vuelve loco porque piensa que toda es la misma instrucción. Tienes que poner el `;` al final, para que quede tal que así:

```
DELETE FROM table_players WHERE userPlayer = 'X' AND passwordPlayer = 'X';
DELETE FROM table_packs WHERE USER_PACK = 'X' AND PASSWORD_PACK = 'X';
DELETE FROM table_questions WHERE USER_QUE = 'X' AND PASSWORD_QUE = 'X';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Justo ese era el error, se me pasó por alto que hay otro "punto y coma" en cada línea.